# Obtener un objeto especifico de una lista en Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular

Tengo una lista de publicaciones en firebase,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy desarrollando un algoritmo para obtener un numero random y con el poder solicitar a firebase un objeto de lst_publicaciones, mi algoritmo random me indica que posición(numero) del objeto es el que debo solicitar, por lo tanto no se que clave tiene este objeto, existe alguna manera de obtener este dato solo con la posición,

Ejemplo

```
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
      const refPublicaciones = vm.rootRef.child(`publicaciones/lst_publicaciones`)
      refPublicaciones.objeto(2).on('value', objeto => {

        console.log(objeto.val());

      })
```

existe algo asi?
saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Usa los cursores de consulta startAt() y limit() que te permiten decidir desde donde comenzar a traer datos y cuantos quieres trae, que en tu caso seria como

```
db.collection('lst_publicaciones')
          .orderBy('descripcion')
          .startAt(randomIndex)
          .limit(1);
```

espero te sirva de algo.
[Aquí la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?hl=es-419)

Comment: La pregunta es usando `Realtime Database` no `Firestore`

Answer (score 0):

La única solución que encontré hasta el momento fue poner un identificador consecutivo a cada publicacion, "id_publicacion" (1,2,3,4,...)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues hacer un filtro para las publicaciones, para que solo regresara la publicacion con el id_publicacion solicitado, aqui el codigo:

```
var random = Math.round(Math.random() * (count-1))+1;
refPublicaciones.orderByChild("id_publicacion").equalTo(random).on('child_added', publicacion => {
  this.lstPublicaciones.push(publicacion.val());
})
```